# Combining two separate javascripts so that they both still work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two scripts that I want to use at the same time:

1.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tabContent").not(":first").hide();
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
        $("ul.tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tabContent").hide();
        $($('a', this).attr("href")).fadeIn('fast');
        return false;
    });
});
```

2.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
```

However, when I just put one after the other in JSfiddle, they don't both work. What is the correct way to be able to put both of these snippets in a single JSfiddle box and have them working.

Comment: Can you share the fiddle??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GYE9s/1/

Comment: I get errors from that `.dialog()` call. Also note that your HTML uses "dialog-modal" for the id, not just "dialog".

Comment: jsfiddle is including a script "<script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com/error.js"></script>" which I think is the issue, it seems to be where it should load jQuery UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting these right after the other should be fine. Are you sure there isn't another error? Also, `$(function(){ ... });` and `(document).ready(function(){ ... });` are the same thing so you can just put `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();` after your click listener in the first piece of code.

Comment: There is an error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on the line trying to use dialog. I think jsfiddle is just broken here since where it looks like it's trying to include jquery-ui I see `//example.com/error.js`

Comment: Added a new URL of jquery UI and cant see any console errors other than a warning: http://jsfiddle.net/GYE9s/5/

Comment: @Jimmy your dialog doesn't work in your new fiddle because you're using `"#dialog"` instead of `"#dialog-modal"`

Comment: Now you're just using the wrong id. You want `#dialog-modal`.